# Overlapping colours for scatterplot in R

Tags: r, colors, scatter-plot

I tried to plot a scatterplot and specify certain colours for some specific values

This is what I got

https://i.stack.imgur.com/h0cBF.jpg

As you can see the "grey" colour is overlapping my other colours

My dataframe has an extra column specifying the different colours to plot

This is the code I used

```
    plot(data$V1,data$V2, pch=20, xlim=c(0,18), ylim = c(-5.5,5.5), col = data$V3,cex =1)
```

Any idea on how to bring the colours to the front and keep the "grey" at the back?

Cheers

Comment: can you please give more information about how your data is organized?

Answer (score 0):

The points are plotted in the same order as they appear in the data frame, so if you reorder your data frame then you will bring the later points to the top.

Maybe something like:

```
with(data[ order(data$V3), ], plot(V1, V2, xlim=c(0,18), ylim=c(-5.5,5.5), col=V3)
```

Or some other ordering.

You may also want to look into making the points transparent.